# Exception.TemplateSyntaxError in flask

Tags: python, exception, flask

I'm trying to run the following code,but am getting error.
Ideally I should be able to navigate to register page.But I am getting an error and not able to navigate.
Ideally i should be able to navigate to Register page.But I am getting an error like this:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
>
> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'login'

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
           <form method="POST" action="">
             {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
             <fieldset class=form-group">
               <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
               <div class="form-group">
                 {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
         {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
               </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                 {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
         {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
         {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
               </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                 {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
         {{ form.confirm(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
               </div>
             </fieldset>
             <div class="form-group">
               {{ form.submit(class='btn-outline-info") }}
             </div>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div class="border-top pt-3">
           <small class="text-muted">
             Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{url_for('login')}}">Sign  In</a>
           </small>
         </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from `{{ form.submit(class='btn-outline-info") }}` where you open the string with single quotes and end it with double quotes.

Try with:

```
{{ form.submit(class="btn-outline-info") }}
```

or

```
{{ form.submit(class='btn-outline-info') }}
```